# Pass a textbox value to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my JSP I have a text box which contain a address path.  I need to pass this address value to `Servlet`.   How to pass a textbox value to servlet?

Comment: open your browser and type google.com

Comment: Your 'java class' being what exactly?  A servlet?  An applet?  Better questions get better answers, but this question so far is very vague.

Comment: I think you want to get text filed value using jsp tag,am I right?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have a servlet class.And I dont know how to get the value from my jsp page.I'm just a beginner in java

Comment: This is covered in chapter 1 of a sane JSP/Servlet tutorial which indicates that you have not really done any research on the subject. I warmly recommend to look for one. See also our servlets tag wiki page (put your mouse on top of `[servlets]` tag until an info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link).

Comment: @BalusC I cant get the link.

Comment: Why did you change your question, post new question otherwise, you are not going to get new answer.

Comment: Rollback to your previous post. Do you think, whatever you will ask, we will solve you problem. This site is for sharing information. So don't do this stupid things.

Comment: @var___ i'm sorry actually I cant post a new question from my profile. That's why i'd edited my previous one.And this site is not allowing the freshers to know something about programming.As a beginner I can't ask the questions upto the standards what it expecting.

Comment: @Unknownuser I noticed, you have silently changed the question. This is not at all accepted in community. I was going through this post and found all unrelated answer, which created so much confusion. If you have some other question, you are supposed to post new question. **never update your original question completely.**

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use Request object to get that value.

Comment: can u please explain by code

Comment: Google it you ll get it
request.getParameter("yourTextName") And Store it into string !!!!
you ll get it

Answer (score 0):

**my.jsp**

```
<form name="myForm" action="myServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mytext" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit name" />
</form>
```

Write the above code inside your `jsp` page (i.e. **my.jsp**).

**myServlet.java**

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String text = request.getParameter("mytext");
 out.println(text);
```

Above code will be written inside your `servlet` page (i.e. **myServlet.java**).

**Note : -** Change form `action` according to your `servlet`. In my case, i have written here **myServlet**.

Comment: Then, why didn't you accepted my answer ??

Comment: I dont know how to accept here

Comment: accepting answer means ticking with green. Right now, you did this. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing JSP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to JSP</h1>
    <form action="myjsp.jsp" method="POST" >
            <input type="text" name="name" />
      <p> 
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit name" />

      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<%
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

%>
```